# Finding Triggering Element of onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on someone's existing code. In the code there are some inline onClick events attached to some input elements, like this one:

```
<input type="button" id="inputID" onClick="someFunction()"/>
```

Problem is that I cannot edit that input's HTML, but I can edit the javascript function declaration of that function.

```
function someFunction(){
     //want to console log the ID of the triggering input element e.g. #inputID
}
```

Is there a way that I could find the ID of the triggering input within the function, without passing any parameters at the time of calling the function (as I cannot edit the HTML)

Comment: Open the console and you can add 'debugger; ' right before the 'someFunction()' directly in the html.  Then you can step into it using the debugger.  For the id itself, instead of debugger (or once the debugger is open) use $(this).attr('id').  You can nest it in a console.log() or just put it directly in the console once the debugger fires.

Comment: @nurdyguy 1) I would assume the OP wants to do this programmatically 2) the `this` reference will be the `window` in a function called from an event attribute, unless the reference is passed as a parameter to the function, which OP states he cannot do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 1. Why would you assume that? 2.  No, the this reference will be will not be to the window but rather to the element clicked.  You can even pass the this reference in the function as a parameter.

Comment: 1) because he has some JS code where he's attempting to get the value...? 2) OP says he can't change the HTML, so how can he pass anything from the onclick attribute?

Comment: Flame? Where exactly have I insulted you? I'm just trying to give people accurate information

Comment: @nurdyguy this inside someFunction is window object indeed, try it

Answer (score 3):

Don't use inline event handlers. Use event listeners:

```js
function someFunction(event) {
  // Use `this` or `event.currentTarget` to get the current target
  console.log(this.id);
}
document.getElementById("inputID").addEventListener('click', someFunction);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="inputID" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: Note that OP says he can't change the HTML, so you'd need to cater with `someFunction()` being called with no `event` being passed. All things being equal, this is the best solution though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Changing the HTML is not necessary. `someFunction` should be moved inside a closure instead of polluting the global scope. Then the inline event handler will throw a `ReferenceError` silently, and the event listener will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global `event` object to achieve this:

```
function someFunction() {
    var el = window.event.target;
    console.log(el.id);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g8epn2of/)

Be aware that this is may have issues in older browsers. An alternative would be to leave the `someFunction()` empty (as you say that you cannot remove  it in the HTML) and instead assign the event handlers through unobtrusive Javascript, from which you can access the element which raised the event through the `this` reference.

Comment: I think target is not supported on window.event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is in newer versions of IE (note that you're linking to the *legacy* browser events guide), but as I stated older browsers may be a problem.

Comment: You're right, inline events are jurassic anyway, and dealing with them is often a headache

Comment: `window.event` is not standard and doesn't work on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however it's not cross browser, in IE it's

```
window.event.srcElement.id
```

In FF and Chrome, you have to pass it to the inline function like

```
someFunction(event)
```

And then you can access it from target property

```
event.target.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you listed in the tags that you're using jQuery, just leave the body of `someFunction` empty and attach an event listener to your inputs that call that function.

```
$('[onclick="someFunction()"]').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k8o1umo4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction() {
  console.log(this.id);
}

var el = document.getElementById("inputID")
//remove inline click event
el.removeAttribute("onclick");
//attach click event
el.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
```

Within the function that was called from addEventListener 'this' will now reference the element from which the event was fired.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Answer (score 0):

## First Way: Send trigger element using `this`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(trigger_element)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = trigger_element

      alert(clicked_element.id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `HTMLElement` and you get the element itself. you don't need to care if the element has an id or any other property. And it works by itself just fine.

---

## Second Way: Send trigger element id using `this.id`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(clicked_id)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = document.getElementById(clicked_id)

      alert(clicked_id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `String` and you DO NOT get the element itself. So before use, you need to make sure that your element already has an id.
>
> You mustn't send the element id by yourself such as `onClick="myFun(btn02)"`. it's not CLEAN CODE and it makes your code lose functionality.

---

in your case it would be:

```
<input type="button" id="inputID" onClick="someFunction(this.id)"/>
```

js:

```
function someFunction(clicked_id){
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = document.getElementById(clicked_id);

      // log your element id
      console.log(typeof tab);
}
```